# Displaying All Minor Ticks on the y-axis of a Log-Log Plot with a Large Y-Axis Range in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create a log-log plot in Matplotlib, where the range of the y-axis is extensive. However, Matplotlib seems to be unable to display all the minor ticks on the y-axis.

Below is the code I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tck

# do the plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.tick_params(which='major', direction='in', width=2, length=7, top=True, right=True, pad=10)
ax.tick_params(which='minor', direction='in', width=1, length=5, top=True, right=True)

plt.xticks(fontsize=18)
plt.yticks(fontsize=18)

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(tck.AutoMinorLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(tck.AutoMinorLocator())

col = ['dodgerblue']

data = np.array([[1.e-1, 4.e-37], [1.e+1, 1.e-33], [1.e+3, 7.e-26]])

plt.loglog(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], col[0], linewidth=2.5)

plt.ylabel(r'$y$', fontsize=22)
plt.xlabel(r'$x$', fontsize=22)

plt.ylim(1e-37, 1e-25)
plt.xlim(0.1, 10000)

locmaj = tck.LogLocator(base=10, numticks=12)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(locmaj)

# Use MultipleLocator to set minor ticks at multiples of the base (10 in this case)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(tck.MultipleLocator(base=10))

# Use LogFormatter for both major and minor ticks to display appropriate scientific notation
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tck.LogFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(tck.LogFormatter())

plt.show()
```

The output plot only displays the major ticks on the y-axis, which [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHNUS.png).

However, I would like to show all the minor ticks. Could anyone please help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you used `locmaj` to get the major ticks, you can set the minor ticks as well. After the `set_major_ticks()`, add these lines AND comment out the other lines in your code as below...

```
# ....
locmaj = tck.LogLocator(base=10, numticks=12)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(locmaj)

## Add the set_minor_locator() code to set the minor ticks.
## Note that the number of ticks will be based on the np.arange(), which has 8 here
locmin = tck.LogLocator(base=10, subs=np.arange(2, 10) * .1)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(locmin)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(tck.NullFormatter())

# Use MultipleLocator to set minor ticks at multiples of the base (10 in this case)
## Commented
#ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(tck.MultipleLocator(base=10))

# Use LogFormatter for both major and minor ticks to display appropriate scientific notation
## Commented
#ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tck.LogFormatter())
## Commented
#ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(tck.LogFormatter())
plt.show()
```

[image]